# Can two PFObjects point at each other?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have two PFObject, I'll call them A and B for simplicity.

1. I create A and save it.
2. I create B, set a property on it called "a" pointing to A and save B
3. I then create a property on A called "b" and then save A

When I try to do that something does not seem to work right, I am trying to understand if it's something else in my code or if Parse does not allow me to have two PFObjects that point at each other.

Can two PFObjects point at each other?

Comment: No. They can't. Are you trying to have B a child of A? and have B store a reference to A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can't (as far as I know).

I came across the same issue. My workaround was to have B store the `objectId` of A, and A store a pointer to B.

Comment: Though I didn't find documentation that supports your answer it doesn't mean there isn't any. For now your answers checks out with what I am experiencing. I did the same thing you did and it all works fine now. So, until somebody else can prove you're "wrong" I will mark this as CORRECT.

Answer (score 3):

They can indeed.  I am assuming that you're not waiting for the save to complete, and it fails because of that.

If you create A and save it, create B pointing to A and save B, then you can point to B on A and save that too.  The saves must be complete though, in between operations.

Regardless, it's not a recommended approach.

```
PFObject *post = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Post"];
PFObject *comment = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Comment"];
[post saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
  [comment setObject:post forKey:@"post"];
  [comment saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    [post setObject:comment forKey:@"comment"];
    [post saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
      // Both objects should be linked now.
    }];
  }];
}];
```

Comment: I think you should double check your answer. One: You can't put a `PFObject` into that type of block. The correct type is `^(BOOL, NSError*)` not `^(PFObject *, NSError *)`Two: The final block is never reached, giving you no way to know when it is done. Three: If you look at these objects in the dashboard afterwards, each comment has a pointer to a post, but the each post does not have any pointer to a comment. I suggest you try this on your own to see how it works.

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried to save the second object after having set a pointer to the other nothing would happen. I can't make it work.

Comment: You're right.. it is not hitting the last completion block.  I wrote the example just free form, so yeah I got the block wrong.  Updated that, but please open a bug report from the bug tool here:  https://parse.com/help

Comment: THIS is the correct answer. I have a similar problem where A has an array of Bs and each B points back to its A. It works fine, but you must use the 3 saves shown above. If you set both pointers and then do two saves, the second save will never return. This is a Parse bug and I have reported it.